# Как правильно обращаться к переменным в методах класса?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, методы

Как правильно обращаться к переменным в методах класса,
если эти переменные объявлены как глобальные в моем проекте?

Как это исправить? Спасибо за помощь.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import Time_code
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys

Mood_Text_Fell = ("How are you?")
mic_Text = ("MIC123")
mic_Text_1 = ("MIC123")
mic_Text_2 = ("MIC123")


Acc_Name = ("NovAndr")

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Well")
        self.setFixedSize(185, 259)

        self.Micro_Button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Micro_Button.setGeometry(55, 79, 74, 129)
        self.Micro_Button.clicked.connect(self.start_microphone)

        self.Settings_Button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Settings_Button.setGeometry(149, -1, 37, 37)

        self.Account_Button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Account_Button.setGeometry(-1, -1, 37, 37)

        self.Mood_Text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.Mood_Text.setText(Mood_Text_Fell)
        self.Mood_Text.setGeometry(37, 222, 111, 18)
        self.Mood_Text.adjustSize()

        self.Account_Name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.Account_Name.setText(Acc_Name)
        self.Account_Name.setGeometry(40, 18, 111, 18)
        


    def start_microphone(self):

        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
        if mic_Text == "MIC123":
            mic_Text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
            self.Mood_Text.setText(mic_Text)
            self.Mood_Text.setGeometry(18, 222, 37, 18)
        elif mic_Text_1 == "MIC123":
            mic_Text_1 = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
            self.YourMessage1 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
            self.YourMessage1.setText(mic_Text_1)
            self.YourMessage1.setGeometry(55, 222, 37, 18)
        elif mic_Text_2 == "MIC123":
            mic_Text_2 = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
            self.YourMessage2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
            self.YourMessage2.setText(mic_Text_2)
            self.YourMessage2.setGeometry(92, 222, 37, 18)
        else:
            print("")





def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('My_project.png'))

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

Comment: Во-первых, переведите вопрос на русский язык. Во-вторых, непонятно кто где кого не видит и что такое «the variable I need», если есть какая-то ошибка — приложите её к тексту вопроса

Comment: Вот перевод: Почему код после def не видит переменные

Comment: @andreymal, у наших соотечественников и соседей на SO - носителей белорусского, русского и украинского языков просто страсть к не очень стандартному английскому :-)  Вас вот смутило что кто-то кого-то не видит ("Кто на ком стоял?" (Булгаков)), а вот англичан, боюсь смутит, что кто-то себя всерьёз зовет чайником, куда воду заливают. При отсутствии такой идиомы в английском языке (правильно переводить: dummy) могут просто испугаться отвечать.

Comment: Просто я английский плохо знаю, поэтому переводчиком пользовался

Comment: Так и пишите по-русски:-) И уж точно не запихивайте в переводчик идиомы. Да фразы покороче делайте и попроще на русском для перевода.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, я не могу проверить ваше приложение
и не совсем понимаю, что в нем должно происходить.

Вы видимо получаете сообщение об ошибке:

> UnboundLocalError: ссылка на локальную переменную mic_Text перед назначением

Один из вариантов как это исправить:

- сделайте `mic_Text_1` и другие переменные объектами класса;
- в любых методах класса обращайтесь к ним `self.mic_Text_1` и т.п.

Да, я также вижу, что эта ошибка исчезнет,
но приложение не будет работать должным образом.
Но это уже совсем другой вопрос.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# ??? import Time_code
import speech_recognition as sr


class Window(QMainWindow):
    Mood_Text_Fell = ("How are you?")                                     # +++
    mic_Text = ("MIC123")                                                 # +++
    mic_Text_1 = ("MIC123")                                               # +++
    mic_Text_2 = ("MIC123")                                               # +++
    Acc_Name = ("NovAndr")                                                # +++

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.Micro_Button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Micro_Button.setGeometry(55, 79, 74, 129)
        self.Micro_Button.clicked.connect(self.start_microphone)
        self.Micro_Button.setToolTip('M_B')

        self.Settings_Button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Settings_Button.setGeometry(149, -1, 37, 37)
        self.Settings_Button.setToolTip('S_B')

        self.Account_Button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Account_Button.setGeometry(-1, -1, 37, 37)
        self.Account_Button.setToolTip('A_B')

        self.Mood_Text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
# +++ -----------------------> vvvv
        self.Mood_Text.setText(self.Mood_Text_Fell)                       # +++ self.
        self.Mood_Text.setGeometry(37, 222, 111, 18)
        self.Mood_Text.adjustSize()

        self.Account_Name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
# +++ --------------------------> vvvv
        self.Account_Name.setText(self.Acc_Name)                          # +++ self.
        self.Account_Name.setGeometry(40, 18, 111, 18)

    def start_microphone(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
# +++ ---> vvvv
        if self.mic_Text == "MIC123":                                     # +++ self.
            mic_Text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
            self.Mood_Text.setText(mic_Text)
            self.Mood_Text.setGeometry(18, 222, 37, 18)
# +++ -----> vvvv            
        elif self.mic_Text_1 == "MIC123":                                 # +++ self.
            mic_Text_1 = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
            self.YourMessage1 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
            self.YourMessage1.setText(mic_Text_1)
            self.YourMessage1.setGeometry(55, 222, 37, 18)
# +++ -----> vvvv
        elif self.mic_Text_2 == "MIC123":                                 # +++ self.
            mic_Text_2 = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
            self.YourMessage2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
            self.YourMessage2.setText(mic_Text_2)
            self.YourMessage2.setGeometry(92, 222, 37, 18)
        else:
            print("")


def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle("Well")
    window.setFixedSize(185, 259)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

Comment: Я хотел сделать так, чтобы у меня когда первое окошко: "недавние" было использовано, появлялось второе и так далее.

Comment: @NovAndr я не понял о чем вы написали в комментариях. То что я вам предложил в своем ответе, отвечает на вопрос - как обращаться к переменным в других методах класса?